# How do fade an image from top to bottom?

Tags: css, fade

I have seen this effect many times and i wanted to try it out on my website now, can someone help me achieve this?
You can look at this website for reference:
https://anime-world.in/

Scroll to the very bottom of the page.

Comment: So.. Did you tried anything?

Comment: i did not, i am confused as to how i am supposed to go about doing that.

Comment: Do you mean how the background image fades so as to allow content to be seen in the middle?

Comment: nevermind, i will figure it out on my own, thanks

Comment: Hmm.. You can inspect the element and copy the structure and style of the thing you want to do, if you have problems with it it's time to ask...

Comment: thanks brother, it is really great to have some give cheerful suggestions than to have suggestions which straight up scold you.